# C++: Why is ofstream not appending or creating new files?

Tags: c++, ofstream

i have a little problem with ofstream. My main calls a certain class several times, each time with different parameters for testing purposes

```
ImageComparison* imco = new ImageComparison(queries[i], j, k, l);
```

Inside each instance i want a formatted output to a file, so i first tried this

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("somepath" + params + ".txt");
ofs << "write results";
ofs.close();
```

I expected that ofstream would create several files, due to different params and therefor different filenames, and write something into it. But it appears that it's always overwriting the former file and just saving the last instance.

 Afterwards i tried to use one file over and over again and appending new lines, since this would be a better solution for my case

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("somename.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
ofs << "write params";
ofs << "write results in same line";
ofs << endl;
ofs.close();
```

In this case it appears that it's not appending new lines, instead it overwrites the former line and in the end i just have the results of the last instance.

 Please enlighten me, i don't have any ideas whats wrong here.

 I appreciate any suggestions/solutions :)

 EDIT: here is concrete case:

 main:

```
vector<string> queries = {"apple","banana","book"...};
for(int i=0; i<18; i++) {
    //if(i==1) break;
    for(int j=0; j<3;) {
        //if(j==2) break;
        for(int k=10; k<800;) {
            //if(k==400) break;
            for(int l=50; l<600;) {
                ImageComparison* imco = new ImageComparison(queries[i], j, k, l);
                imco->DoImCo();
                delete imco;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ImageComparison.cc:

```
string bloo = "../ImageData/" + m_object_type + "/" + m_object_type + "metric=" + to_string(m_metric) + ",hessian=" + to_string(m_hessian) + ",words" + to_string(m_number_of_words) + ".txt";
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open(bloo.c_str(), ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
for(int i=0; i<image_names.size(); i++) {
    if(similarity_of_one[i] < similarity_average) {
        ofs << " x";
    }else{
        ofs << " v";
    }
}
ofs << endl;
ofs.close();
```

EDIT2: forgot parameter increase inside the "for's" but not important i think

Comment: @jrok: Don't need `ofstream::in` unless you want to retain the content and at the same time not append. (e.g. you want to alter an existing part of the file using seek and some write functionality)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Right, I thought for a moment that `out` implies `trunc` or something like that.

Comment: @Auberotte Can you construct a minimal complete test case?

Comment: @jrok I have a small test case, for now i am just using 4 parameter sets or did i missunderstand you?

Comment: @Auberotte Good, you have a small test case, now can you post it here? Hard to help otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try starting a new project with only this part of your example code? Doesn't it append new lines for you?

> Blockquote

```
ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("somename.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::app);
ofs << "write params";
ofs << "write results in same line";
ofs << endl;
ofs.close();
```

Try to use ofstream::app only, it will automatically create new file for you. Frankly, I don't see any problem with the above code.

(Sorry I never made an answer. It looks lame :( )

Comment: I thought that if `ofstream::app` i could open a file multiple times, instead of creating new ones or does it really create new files, in my case overwriting the old one?

Comment: Yes, you could open the file multiple times. For the first time when it doesn't exist, the file will be created.

Comment: Ok, i made a new test project and it worked as it should, even under similar circumstances as my main project, thats strange...

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i found something. It seems that there were a problem with the name. After using a constant name like "../Test.txt" it worked fine, sill don't know why but the problem is gone. Big thx for all your suggestions.